# How to parse a string of boolean logic in PHP

Tags: php, string, logic, boolean

I'm building a PHP class with a private member function that returns a string value such as:

```
'true && true || false'
```

to a public member function.  (This string is the result of some regex matching and property lookups.)  What I'd like to do is have PHP parse the returned logic and have the aforementioned public function return whether the boolean result of the parsed logic is true or false.

I tried eval(), but I get no output at all.  I tried typecasting the boolean returns...but there's no way to typecast operators...hehe  Any ideas?  (Let me know if you need more information.)

Comment: did you try eval("return " . $mystring)?

Answer (score 29):

Just stumbled upon this question, but being fairly uneasy about using `eval`, I decided to keep looking for a better solution.

What I discovered is yet another wonderful use for PHP's [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function, when passing in the `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN` flag ([of which there are many](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php)).

This "one line" function seems to do well at *safely* converting a string (or other) object to a boolean:

```
<?php

/**
 * Uses PHP's `filter_var` to validate an object as boolean
 * @param string $obj The object to validate
 * @return boolean
 */
function parse_boolean($obj) {
    return filter_var($obj, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
}
```

And, a little testing:

```
/**
 * Let's do some testing!
 */
$tests = array (
    "yes",
    "no",
    "true",
    "false",
    "0",
    "1"
);

foreach($tests as $test) {

    $bool = parse_boolean($test);

    echo "TESTED: ";
    var_dump($test); 

    echo "GOT: ";
    var_dump($bool);

    echo "\n\n";

}
```

**Output:**

```
/*
TESTED: string(3) "yes"
GOT: bool(true)


TESTED: string(2) "no"
GOT: bool(false)


TESTED: string(4) "true"
GOT: bool(true)


TESTED: string(5) "false"
GOT: bool(false)


TESTED: string(1) "0"
GOT: bool(false)


TESTED: string(1) "1"
GOT: bool(true)
*/
```

I haven't looked deep enough, but it's possible that this solution relies on `eval` down the line somewhere, however I'd still side with using those over plain `eval`ing since I assume that `filter_var` would also handle sanitizing any input before piping it through `eval`.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the original problem (in that operators are not handled).  `filter_var('true && true', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)` returns `false`.

Comment: Absolutely. This was a misunderstanding of the original question on my part, and should be unmarked as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 3):

`eval()` will work perfectly fine for this, but remember you have to tell it to return something.

```
$string = "true && true || false";
$result = eval("return (".$string.");"); // $result will be true
```

Also make sure you sanitize any user inputs if putting them directly into an `eval()`.

Comment: Thanks; I was forgetting the 'return'.  The string is the result of a rather tight regex, so I think I'll be fine.  I'll re-assess the sanitizing now that this is working.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume eval() is an ok/good solution in your case.

```
class Foo {
  private function trustworthy() {
    return 'true && true || false';
  }

  public function bar() {
    return eval('return '.$this->trustworthy().';');
  }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$r = $foo->bar();
var_dump($r);
```

prints `bool(true)`

Comment: Thanks for your help; I was indeed forgetting the 'return'...hehe