# How to parse true and false string in an array to become booleans

Tags: php, arrays, boolean

How do I parse the `true` and `false` string in an array to become boolean if they exist?

For instance,

form

```
$config = array(
    "allow_n" => "true",
    "allow_m" => "false",
    "say"     => "hello"
);
```

to

```
$config = array(
    "allow_n" => true,
    "allow_m" => false,
    "say"     => "hello"
);
```

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

Thanks guys for the help.

Sorry I forgot to clarify from the beginning - this case may happen in a multidimentinal array, for instance,

```
$config = array(
    "allow_n" => "true",
    "allow_m" => "false",
    "say"     => "Hello",
    "php"   => array(
        "oop" => "true",
        "classic" => "false"
    )
);
```

Comment: Is your question really about this super-simple string comparison, or is it about how to walk through a multidimensional array?  If the latter, then maybe you should consider changing the title of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `array_walk_recursive` to achieve this :

Example

```
$config = array (
        "allow_n" => "true",
        "allow_m" => "false",
        "say" => "Hello",
        "php" => array (
                "oop" => "true",
                "classic" => "false" 
        ) 
);
var_dump ( $config );

array_walk_recursive ( $config, function (&$item) {
    if ($item == "true") {
        $item = true;
    } else if ($item == "false") {
        $item = false;
    } else if (is_numeric ( $item )) {
        $item = intval ( $item );
    }
} );

var_dump ( $config );
```

Output Before

```
'allow_n' => string 'true' (length=4)
  'allow_m' => string 'false' (length=5)
  'say' => string 'Hello' (length=5)
  'php' => 
    array
      'oop' => string 'true' (length=4)
      'classic' => string 'false' (length=5)
```

Output After

```
    array
  'allow_n' => boolean true
  'allow_m' => boolean false
  'say' => string 'Hello' (length=5)
  'php' => 
    array
      'oop' => boolean true
      'classic' => boolean false
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($config as $k=>$v)
{
  $low_v = strtolower($v);
  if ($low_v == 'true')
    $config[$k] = true;
  else if ($low_v == 'false')
    $config[$k] = false; 
}
```

Comment: The result of `strtolower($v)` doesn't change, why call it 2 times

Comment: I don't think the performance degradation that the second call will introduce would be of any considerable significance, unless, of course, the array `$config` is extremely huge.

Comment: The issue is not performance, the issues with copy paste programming should be well known. What If I need to add `"null"` ? What if after this I need to modify it to `mb_strtolower` etc. It's just far more easier to maintain when you minimize the moving parts.

Comment: @Esailija Much better arguments in the follow-up comment ;-)

Comment: @Aziz thanks for the answer but a multidimensional array will break your code... please see my edit above. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a loop that would do it

```
foreach ($config as $key => $val) {
    if ($val == 'true') {
        $config[$key] = true;
    } elseif ($val == 'false') {
        $config[$key] = false;
    }
}
```

Edit: Here's a function for recursion and handling multi-dimensional arrays

```
function tfSwap($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $arr[$key] = tfSwap($val);
        } else {
            if ($val == 'true') {
                $arr[$key] = true;
            } elseif ($val == 'false') {
                $arr[$key] = false;
            }
        }
    }  
    return $arr;
}
```

Then you could just call it like this:

```
$config = tfSwap($config);
```

Answer (score 1):

I''m sure there are other solutions, but you should be able to use the [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function and pass in the `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN` flag. That'll give you a one-liner in stead of writing out a loop. :)

```
filter_var($config, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

// edit: same as suggested here: [How to parse a string of boolean logic in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761215/how-to-parse-a-string-of-boolean-logic-in-php)

Comment: @pst: Good point, I completely overlooked that one. Unfortunately there's no flag appropriate flag to keep the value in case it's not recognised as a boolean (only a return-null-flag-if-no-boolean flag), so this is indeed no going to help the OP. Thanks for pointing it out to me!

Answer (score 1):

You could also maintain an array of the conversions, and look in there while iterating over the array.

```
$map = array("true" => true, "false"  => false);
foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($value, $map)) {
        $config[$key] = $map[$value];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be like:

```
function boolify( $var ) {
    if( is_array( $var ) ) foreach( $var as $ek=>$ev ) $ret[$ek] = boolify( $ev );
    else if( $var === 'false' ) $ret = false;
    else if( $var === 'true' ) $ret = true;         
    else $ret = $var;
    return $ret;
}

$config = array(
    "allow_n" => "true",
    "allow_m" => "false",
    "say"     => "Hello",
    "php"   => array(
        "oop" => "true",
        "classic" => "false"
    )
);

$config = boolify( $config ); 

var_dump( $config );

// output: array(4) { ["allow_n"]=> bool(true) ["allow_m"]=> bool(false) ["say"]=> string(5) "Hello" ["php"]=> array(2) { ["oop"]=> bool(true) ["classic"]=> bool(false) } }
```